# setup FTP/sftp server on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver with VSFTPD not working (Closed)

Tags: ftp, sftp

Installed ftp following [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd). Unable to connect to ftp with command

```
  $ ftp ubuntu-ftp
```

output is-

```
 $ ftp: ubuntu-ftp: Name or service not known, 
 $ ftp>
```

again I used

```
$ sudo systemctl start vsftpd
$ sudo systemctl enable vsftpd
```

but not worked for me.

before installing ftp I installed sftp with [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd)

output was-

```
$ sftp sftpuser@ubuntu-sftp
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu-sftp: Name or service not known
Connection closed
```

please help!
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you predefined `ubuntu-sftp` in `/etc/hosts`? If not, there’s nothing defining where `ubuntu-sftp` should be going. If you’re testing on the same machine, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If you’re testing on a different machine, use the IP address of the SFTP server 

Comment: I defined 127.0.2.1 ubuntu-sftp on  /etc/hosts used command sftp sftpuser@ubuntu-sftp It worked for me. Thanks a lot! @Matigo